# Github Pages (https://account.github.io/project) after auth0 login to incorrect URL

Tags: vue.js, auth0, quasar-framework

I am trying to deploy my Vue3 SPA app on GitHub pages and everything is working as its supposed to. I have the callback and redirect_uri set to “https://account.github.io/<repo_name>”. However, after I login, I am redirected to only “https://account.github.io” and the page does load but I cannot navigate to anything else nor can I refresh or else I am hit with a 404 error.

I have been looking online and reading through anything I can find, but I cannot seem to resolve this issue. If anyone can help I would gladly appreciate it.

I have tried searching for a solution online but nothing came up. I have also tried multiple allowed callback urls but only https://account.github.io/repo-name seems to work. I also changed the router mode to hash instead of history. Although with the one that is working, it is still not properly redirecting to the correct page instead I get redirected to "https://account.github.io" and obviously that cannot be found.

Here is the code initializing my auth0 on startup.
auth0.js:

```
import { createAuth0 } from "@auth0/auth0-vue";

export default ({ app }) => {
    app.use(
        createAuth0({
            domain: <domain_name>,
            clientId: <client_id>,
            authorizationParams: {
                redirect_uri: "https://account.github.io/<repo_name>",
            },
        })
    );

};
```